# Debugging a single java test method in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, junit

I have a test class that contains several test methods and I want to single out a test method to **debug**. So the first question is: Can I do this in Eclipse? or am I only allowed to debug the whole test class?

Also, when running the test class as a Junit without debugging, it finishes all the tests fairly quickly. But when debugging, some of the tests take extremely longer to complete. Here is a screenshot of the time taken when debugging:

[image]

The first method in the screenshot takes just over a second when running the test class, but takes almost 250 seconds to finish when debugging! This method tests another method that is supposed to simulate insertion in a database engine; it tests insertion into a table by taking a lot of entries and inserting them in respective tables. So the second question is: why is it taking a very long time when debugging? Again, I am using Eclipse IDE. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To debug a single test, right-click on the test and then choose `Debug As > JUnit Test`.

Also, do not forget to set breakpoints where needed.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my first question!